# SwiftUI: Number pad layout

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm building a custom number pad in Swift UI. I want the buttons to be arranged in a grid that fills the screen. The only way I've found to do this for far is to use `GeometryReader` but this seems like overkill for this simple task. Is there a better way to write this?

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach([a, b, c]) { n in
            Button(action: { self.add(n) }) { Text("\(n)") }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3)
        }
    }
}.frame(height: 80)
```

This results in this, which is how I want it to look. Just curious if there is a good way to do this without `GeometryReader`.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're building it custom instead of using a text field with a number pad keyboard type?

Comment: I want a custom design :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without `GeometryReader`. You just have to make each key view expandable. Then your `HStack` and `VStack` will take care of the rest.

A `Button` tightly wraps its label subview, so you need to make the label subview expandable. A `Color` is a `View` that expands to fill whatever space it's given, so let's use `Color.clear` as the button's label, and overlay the real `Text` label on the `Color`. I think we should define a `KeyPadButton` `View` for this:

```
struct KeyPadButton: View {
    var key: String

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.action(self.key) }) {
            Color.clear
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .stroke(Color.accentColor))
                .overlay(Text(key))
        }
    }

    enum ActionKey: EnvironmentKey {
        static var defaultValue: (String) -> Void { { _ in } }
    }

    @Environment(\.keyPadButtonAction) var action: (String) -> Void
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var keyPadButtonAction: (String) -> Void {
        get { self[KeyPadButton.ActionKey.self] }
        set { self[KeyPadButton.ActionKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct KeyPadButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        KeyPadButton(key: "8")
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
#endif
```

I've defined an `EnvironmentKey` so that we can use the environment to pass the action callback from the higher-level keypad view to all the buttons.

`KeyPadButton` looks like this:

[image: KeyPadButton preview]

If you don't like the border, just remove that modifier.

Note that I've manually set the size of the button in the `PreviewProvider`. Since this view is expandable, it'll preview at the device size by default, and we don't need to see one giant button.

Now let's define a `KeyPadRow` view to lay out one row of buttons:

```
struct KeyPadRow: View {
    var keys: [String]

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(keys, id: \.self) { key in
                KeyPadButton(key: key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can define the `KeyPad` view to lay out the entire keypad and provide the action for the buttons:

```
struct KeyPad: View {
    @Binding var string: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            KeyPadRow(keys: ["1", "2", "3"])
            KeyPadRow(keys: ["4", "5", "6"])
            KeyPadRow(keys: ["7", "8", "9"])
            KeyPadRow(keys: [".", "0", "⌫"])
        }.environment(\.keyPadButtonAction, self.keyWasPressed(_:))
    }

    private func keyWasPressed(_ key: String) {
        switch key {
        case "." where string.contains("."): break
        case "." where string == "0": string += key
        case "⌫":
            string.removeLast()
            if string.isEmpty { string = "0" }
        case _ where string == "0": string = key
        default: string += key
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, let's define a `ContentView` that shows the string above the keypad:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(string)
            }.padding([.leading, .trailing])
            Divider()
            KeyPad(string: $string)
        }
        .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding()
    }

    @State private var string = "0"

}


#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Here's the final result:

[image: demo]

Comment: Oh wow, this is some next level SwiftUI! This will take me a bit to go through :)

Comment: Lots of great content in this post, thanks so much! Looks like `Color.clear.overlay` as the button content was the big missing piece for my original question.

Comment: are there any good resources you can recommend to learn more about how `EnvironmentValues` work to do things like this and how this is working?

Comment: Seems like with the current version of SwiftUI, you cannot round the corners of the border and instead need to use `.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).stroke(Color.accentColor))` to achieve this same effect.

Comment: How in the world did you copy the SF Symbol "delete left" like this as a string in your keypad rows definition ???

Comment: I didn't. That is a standard Unicode character, U+232B ERASE TO THE LEFT.